# How do I setup multiple Squid proxies on the same EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, squid

I'm trying to setup multiple Squid proxies on a single EC2 instance.

I've followed this https://askubuntu.com/a/680691 but I can't seem to get it working.

I have assigned two elastic IPs to the instance. I can connect to the first IP as a proxy but the second one fails.

Here is my squid config:

```
http_port 172.xx.xx.215:3128 name=3128
http_port 172.xx.xx.64:3129 name=3129

acl tasty3128 myportname 3128 src 172.xx.xx.0/20
http_access allow tasty3128
tcp_outgoing_address 172.xx.xx.215 tasty3128

acl tasty3129 myportname 3129 src 172.xx.xx.0/20
http_access allow tasty3129
tcp_outgoing_address 172.xx.xx.64 tasty3129

cache deny all
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache_log /dev/null

refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320

acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl SSL_ports port 1-65535
acl Safe_ports port 1-65535
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all

forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all
```